# How to overflow auto focus last element

Tags: javascript, css, electron, styles

I develop Todo App. İf add to new element, scrollbars not focusing bottom of the page. How can i solve this problem ?

[image: How can I automatically fix it to the bottom all the time?]

Comment: You could use a `MutationObserver` to detect changes inside the Todo element, and update the element's `scrollTop` on change.

Comment: What content is down there when you scroll to end of page? It does appear that "This is" is continues beneath your text box and beyond

Comment: When I add items, the scroll doesn't go down, it stays up constantly

Comment: Not saying you should or shouldn't, but am asking, do you include jQuery in this project?

Comment: Perhaps show your code also. Can't recommend changes without that

Comment: Not use Jquery just pure JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of Element.scrollIntoView() after adding it.

For example:

```
function addElement(text) {
   // create a new element
   const element = document.createElement('p');
   element.innerText = text;

   // get the list where you want to add the element 
   const list = document.getElementById("myList");
   list.appendChild(element);

   // scroll to it
   element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

For more information's about compatibility you should have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView it is marked as experimental, but all common browsers support it.